# How to create two tables in a apex:pageBlockSection

Tags: apex, visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, pageblock, pagelayoutassignment

[image]

I want to develope somthing like this screenshot in an apex:pageBlockSection. How can i develop this??

Answer (score 10):

Just insert two pageBlockTables to the pageBlockSection with parameter `columns="2"`:

```
<apex:pageBlock id="mainBlock">
    <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!alist}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!alist}" var="a">
            <apex:column value="{!a.name}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Result:

[image]